# how could we create this tree diagram?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tikz-trees

How could we create the following tree diagram in a seperate page which has horizontal landscape?

[image: this]

Comment: What is the problem? The tree or the “separate page and landscape” thing? What have you tried? Have you seen [tag:forest]?

Comment: Actually both. I'm gonna check this out, but any help is more than welcome.

Comment: For the landscape part, take a look at [tag:landscape] and the `lscape` package.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A rough answer based on `forest`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\forestset{
  L1/.style={fill=green,},
  L2/.style={fill=orange,edge={orange,line width=2pt}},
  L3/.style={fill=yellow,edge={yellow,line width=2pt}},
  L4/.style={fill=pink,edge={pink,line width=2pt}},
}

\begin{forest}
    for tree={
        grow=0,reversed, % tree direction
        parent anchor=east,child anchor=west, % edge anchors
        edge={line cap=round},outer sep=+1pt, % edge/node connection
        rounded corners,minimum width=15mm,minimum height=8mm, % node shape
        l sep=10mm % level distance
    }
  [AAAA,L1
    [EEEE,L2
        [EEEE,L3
            [YYYY,L4][AAAA,L4]
        ]
        [DDDD,L3
            [DDDD,L4][KKKK,L4]
        ]
        [PPPP,L3
            [KKKK,L4][KKKK,L4]
        ] 
    ]
    [OOOO,L2]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm really disappointed in you, Kevin, for not copying the exact text from the original ;)

Comment: Maybe `edge={line cap=round}` and `outer sep=+1pt` (for `draw`n nodes: `outer sep=\pgflinewidth+1pt`) to have nicer edges and better edge/node connection?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Thanks for the tip! The answer is updated.

Comment: @Christian: I don't know... It's all Greek to me :-p

Comment: `grow=east` instead of a vague "0"