# Square Edge and Horizontal Tree Diagramm with forest

Tags: diagrams, trees, forest

I am basically trying to re-create the Aves Cladogram as illustrated in [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_birds#Phylogeny).

After trying to use `Newicktree` [package](http://cbr.jic.ac.uk/dicks/software/newicktree/) for a while, I decided to migrate to `forest`.

I am trying to make an horizontal and squared edge tree combining answer from [Square edges in forest package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108710/square-edges-in-forest-package) and [how could we create this tree diagram?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119053/how-could-we-create-this-tree-diagram).

Here is my current code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={
    edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}](\forestOve{\forestove{@parent}}{name}.parent anchor) -- +(0,-12pt)-|     (\forestove{name}.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};},
    grow=0,
    reversed, % tree direction
    parent anchor=east,
    child anchor=west, % edge anchors
}
[VP
    [DP,tier=word]
    [V’
        [V,tier=word]
        [DP,tier=word]
    ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

And as expected the result is not desirable:

[image: Imgur]

My guess is that I should modify `-- +(0,-12pt)-|`, but I don't know how !
Many thanks for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer will work but is needlessly verbose as you can simply use relative node names to specify the `edge path`.

```
      \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}](!u.parent anchor) -- +(5pt,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};},
```

`(!u)` refers to the parent of the current node. `()` refers to the current node.

You can also align the terminal nodes for the whole tree in the preamble:

```
    if n children=0{tier=word}{}
```

but anchoring the nodes at the left side makes for a neater tree:

```
    anchor=west,
```

The result:

[image: neater tree]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}](!u.parent anchor) -- +(5pt,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};},
    grow=0,
    reversed, % tree direction
    parent anchor=east,
    child anchor=west, % edge anchors
    anchor=west,
    if n children=0{tier=word}{}
}
[VP
    [DP]
    [V’
        [V]
        [DP]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: However, I have a little offset for some entry on last entry (last right element). see [code](https://github.com/Rafnuss/Aves-Cladogram/blob/master/latex.tex) and [pdf](https://github.com/Rafnuss/Aves-Cladogram/blob/master/latex.pdf)

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you saying that your tree should or shouldn't look like that?! You probably don't want to set the children's anchors to `north` when nodes are empty, though. `west` would be better here.

Comment: I can't compile your full code: I get an error about too large a dimension.

Comment: @Rafnuss `delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,for parent={for children={anchor=west}}}{}}` solves both the compilation error and the alignment problem for me. (Assuming the alignment was a problem, and not intended - as I say, I wasn't clear on that.)

Comment: @Rafnuss [Output with adjustment](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HqBZl.png).

Comment: Instead of square edges, how can make the edge joints little round? like, {

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `tikz` is not that bad...

After looking a little more at the manuel and few test here it is `-- +(8pt,0) |-` or complete version:

```
edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}] (\forestOve{\forestove{@parent}}{name}.parent anchor) -- +(8pt,0) |- (\forestove{name}.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};}
```

[image: Imgur]

From what i understand, `--` is for drawing a line, `+(x,y)` is the lenght of the line and `-|` or `|-` for perpendicular line either vertical or horizontal. So `-- +(8pt,0)` create the small horizontal line from the parent node and `|-` make the perpendicular line.

I still don't know how the two end of line (from perpendicular line to child node) is drawn...

Comment: `|-` actually makes *two* line segments (vertical first, and then horizontal) and so does `-|`, but in reverse order.