# forest styling - Horizontal tree similar to a folder tree

Tags: formatting, tikz-styles, forest

I would like to obtain the following formatting for a tree **with the excellent package `forest` only**. Maybe the example in page 82 of the documentation or [this other post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278810/square-edge-and-horizontal-tree-diagramm-with-forest) could be a starting point.

[image]

Here is the code for a horizontal standard tree.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    for tree = {%
        grow'  = 0,
        l      = 2.5cm,
        parent anchor=east,
        s sep  = 1.2cm,
    },
    [
        [A
            [B]
            [C
                [D]
                [E]
            ]
        ]
        [F]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

With plain `tikz`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=2pt] (0,0)node(a){}--(12,0)node[fill=white](B){B};
\node[fill=white]at ($(a)!0.50!(B)$) (A) {A};
\node[fill=white, below=of A, yshift=-4cm] (F){F};
\draw[line width=2pt] ($(a)!0.10!(B)$) |-(F);
\node[fill=white, below=of B, yshift=-1cm] (C){C};
\draw[line width=2pt] ($(a)!0.60!(B)$) |-(C);
\node[fill=white, right=of C, xshift=2cm] (D){D};
\draw[line width=2pt] (C) --(D);
\node[fill=white, below=of D, yshift=-1cm] (E){E};
\draw[line width=2pt] ($(C)!0.20!(D)$) |-(E);
\end{tikzpicture}

    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I really need to do that with forest because this would be a way among another to display probabilistic trees.