# How can I compile Metapost code using PdfLaTeX?

Tags: pdftex, metapost

I'm working on the website [ShareLaTeX](https://fr.sharelatex.com/) and I want to adapt the code giving by [thruston](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/15036/thruston) in this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426844/how-to-draw-diagram/428866?noredirect=1#comment1074065_428866) with the compiler PdfLaTeX instead of LuaLaTeX. I already tried to change the compiler in ShareLaTeX from PdfLaTeX to LuaLaTeX but it didn't work I guess it's due to other package I'm using in my memoir. This is my documant class :

```
\documentclass[headings=big,twoside,chapterprefix=true,fleqn]{scrreprt}
```

How can I adapt the code with PdfLaTeX  ?

Comment: I see, I will try to realize my diagram with the forest package again.

Comment: @marmot that is essentially metapost so you (should) be able to extract the metapost code compile with metapost to get a pdf file and then include in to pdftex but I do not know any "automatic"  packaged conversion (and I haven't used metapost this century so I don't think I'll attempt an answer:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I created a new project in ShareLaTeX and I compiled the code (by thruston) with LuaLaTeX and I was able to download the pdf file, so I'll just put this file in my Memoir (screeprt document) thank you for the trick.

Comment: @RedOne oh that's easier/better than I suggested (which was to run metapost "by hand" you could post a self answer:-)

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do this, is to create a new empty project in ShareLaTeX and copy the code of the diagramme given by [thruston](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/15036/thruston) in it and then compile using LuaLaTeX instead of PdfLaTeX. After that I dowlonad the pdf file and put it in my principal document to get the result.